# How deserialize [JsonExtensionData] Dictionary<string, object> with casting

Tags: c#, json.net

[JsonExtensionData] allows you to do is to serialize elements of a JSON document which does not have matching properties on the destination object to the dictionary which is decorated with the [JsonExtensionData] attribute.

How to create a dictionary of objects cast into the appropriate type??

For example:

```
var json = "{\r\n \"sampleClass\":{ \"name\":\"Name\"} ,             
\"sampleOtherClass\":{ \"name\":\"OtherName\"} ,\r\n  \"X\": \"Jan\"\r\n}";
```

and

```
var result  =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);
```

and

```
public class Test
{
    public string X { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Y { get; set; }
}
```

The dictionary should contain such elements:

```
Dictionary<string, object> students = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "sampleClass", new ClassName { Name="MyName" } },
    { "sampleOtherClass", new SampleOtherClass { Name="MyName" } }
};
```

Which means that for node sampleClass we want to create object SampleClass and next to add the dictionary Y.

Currently, the value in the DictionaryEntry is a string e.g. { name: "Name" }

The source:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/mhU6ME

**Update:**

Now I used the below approach to deserialize, but when I want to have one     [JsonExtensionData] Dictionary to deserialize/serialize  it brings problems to have two collections.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken> _JTokenProperty { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, PropertiesClass> Properties1 { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, PropertiesClass>();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a data-structure storing instances that seem to have **nothing** in common in a single **common** map? But anyway: what is your problem exactly? What results do you get?

Comment: The reason is that the rest api returns user-defined objects.

Comment: Currently, the key and the string as value are created { "key", "{name: "Name"} }

Comment: I think you have to write your custom serializer and within that you hjave to tell Json.net of what type those properties are. I have made a quick search and it seems that here you find a simple example on how this may work. I have not testet this yet. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40439958/9809950

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse not fully corresponding json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279441/how-to-parse-not-fully-corresponding-json)

Comment: The problem is that I need one [JsonExtensionData] Dictionary<string,object> to (de)serialize. The solution with [JsonExtensionData] public Dictionary<string, JToken> _JTokenProperty { get; set; } is not accurate because it does not give possibilty to serialize ??

Comment: Related or duplicate: [How to deserialize a child object with dynamic (numeric) key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40088941/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

Json.Net has the ability to (de)serialize objects specifying the actual type of the object.

In the serialization process a property `"$type"` for storing the Type is added to the resulting JSON. Then in deserialization this property is checked to obtain the actual Type.
Of course it must be a Type which inherits/implements the declared Type in you class.
Since you're using `object`, you shouldn't have problems.

You can activate this feature by setting the `TypeNameHandling` property of the `JsonSerializerSettings` to `Auto`, which activates this behaviour when the object type is different from the declared type.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#TypeNameHandling

Comment: However this is not my restful service that's why it does not return $type and I do not have the option of adding $type

Comment: How, then, the program is supposed to decide which is the correct type? If you need to make assumptions based on things such as the name of the property (the key of the dictionary) or the content of the object, I think the only way is to write your own `JsonConverter` and place your custom logic into the `ReadJson` method.

Comment: Now I used [OnDeserialized] private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)

Answer (score -2):

how about if you try the dynamic instance instead of object.

```
public class Test
{
    public string X { get; set; }

    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Y { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion that does not give us possibility to cast.